# Change name of sg.Print window in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, printing, pysimplegui

At the beginning of my python code I have print = sg.Print . So whenever print is used, it prints to a Window called Debug Window. According to documentation, I can close the window with sg.PrintClose() and that works, but I can't change or set the name of the Debug Window.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a4fT.png)

I also tried the following to send to GUI output box:

```
def sg_Print(*args, **kwargs):
    output_element = window['-OUTPUT-']
    output_text = output_element.get()  # get current text in element
    output_element.update(value=output_text + '\n' + ' '.join(map(str, args)))

print = sg_Print
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a window (debugWindow in the example) then you can set the title and all the other properties you would like.  Then you redirected Stdout to it and use the normal print statements in python.  Turn off redirecting when you are done.

Here is simple code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

title = "Debug Window"
debugWindow = sg.Window(title, [
     [sg.Multiline("This is for Output:\n", k='--DEBUG--', size= (50,20))],
     [sg.B("Close")]], finalize=True)
print("This will go to Stdout:")
debugWindow['--DEBUG--'].reroute_stdout_to_here()
print("This will goto the multi line box")
for i in range(25):
    debugWindow.read(timeout=50)
    if i == 15:
        print("This is last to multi-line box")
        debugWindow['--DEBUG--'].restore_stdout()
    print(f"Message #{i}")
```

Comment: This was really helpful for me! I only tried the reroute_stdout_to_here() function and gets me very close. But the program waits until completion to send to the multi-line box, unlike sg.Print. Does your suggestion send in real-time? Thanks!

Comment: On second thought, I think your answer is the solution, thanks! If I add the following when creating sg.Multiline: auto_refresh=True,reroute_stdout=True, autoscroll=True, it works.  To maintain the same space on the screen, I reduced the GUI output box size by 9/10 and reduced that font, since now almost all of the information is printed directly to the Multiline box. The end result is exactly what I was looking for, much appreciated.

Comment: @BioFind17, if you think that my answer is the solution you were looking for, would you please rate up the answer.  I am new to this site and can use a higher rating.

Comment: I tried to but it said I was too new to rate up answers. Thanks though!